# Try Catch in Async Methods

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello everyone i have a question in the next following piece of code the line **await Task.Run(() => adapter.Fill(dataTable));** if it fails the try catch block does not handle the exception. How i can catch the exception?

Thank you.

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetSettingsConenction()))
        {
            try
            {
                await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                string query = "SELECT [dbo].[User].[usr_id] AS \"ID\", [dbo].[User].[usr_alias] AS \"ALIAS\", [dbo].[User].[usr_firstname] AS \"NOMBRE\", [dbo].[User].[usr_lastname] AS \"APELIIDO\", [dbo].[User].[usr_email] AS \"MAIL\", (SELECT [dbo].[UserRole].[uro_name] FROM [dbo].[UserRole] WHERE [dbo].[UserRole].[uro_id] LIKE [dbo].[User].usr_urol_id) AS \"ROL\" FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE [dbo].[User].[usr_deleted] NOT LIKE '1'";
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = SQL_TIMEOUT_EXECUTION_COMMAND;

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                await Task.Run(() => adapter.Fill(dataTable));
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return dataTable;
            }
            catch
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
[image]

After open the connection i simulate a lost of internet connection, and when it trays to fill the datatable the exception apperas. Say TimeOut exception

Comment: why don't you call the Fill directly? why do you use a task?

Comment: `if it fails the try catch block does not handle the exception` Are you sure about that? Can you post a minimal repro?

Comment: Why do you explicitly close the connection? The using block takes care of that for you. Why do you return null if there's an error? That's just going to hide the problem, and be indistinguishable from no users in the table. Only catch exceptions at a place where you will actually branch your execution to do something else.

Comment: If you want to execute certain code on all paths, use `try/catch/finally`

Comment: @Jonesopolis Sure, but there's no need for that here. The using block will close the connection for us.

Comment: @Jonesopolis the problem is right on the Close. It fires a new task, and if that lasts long enough, the connection will be closed before the Fill ends.

Comment: "it fails the try catch block does not handle the exception" - what does that mean? What are you actually seeing?

Comment: If you continue executing the code, you will see that it goes into the catch block. You are executing the code in the debugging mode, so this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The actual question**

The piece of code you show to us does in fact handle the error thrown by `await Task.Run(() => adapter.Fill(dataTable));`

As soon as you `await` the `async` method, the `exception` will get caught by the surrounding `try catch` block.

Also refer to this small sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/PwLEPD

**using vs try catch**

Since you are already declaring your `SqlConnection` within a `using` statement, the connection will be properly closed/disposed anyways.

A using block is basically a `try finally` that disposes all resources declared in the `using`. The `close` in your `catch block` is followed up by the auto `dispose` (including `close`) of the `using`.

**About the screenshot**

Your debugger stops at the exception when it's thrown. This does not mean your catch block will not get hit. Set a breakpoint into it and you will realize, after you press continue, you will hit it.